# IPv6 VPN addressing

Tags: vpn, ipv6

I got two servers with public IPv4 and (now) IPv6 addresses. They have a VPN to do stuff like MySQL replication. With IPv4 I just took a RFC1918 range (10.0.0.0/8) and if you access the server via that range, it went through the VPN. With IPv6 everything has a globally unique address without NAT. How would you assign addresses to the endpoints? I got on each side a /48 subnet.

I see the following possibilities:

1. Use a private/documentation/... IPv6 address
2. Somehow route the traffic to the public IPv6 address through the VPN

How would you do it?
VPN is tinc.

Comment: Documentational space is never a good idea, it has one very specific purpose. What endpoints are you talking about, the clients? Or are those servers connected with eachother through a VPN?

Comment: The server are connected with eachother.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

General rule of thumb: never use documentational space. It has a very specific purpose, don't ever use it for anything else or you'll regret it at a later time.

If these two servers only need to talk to eachother and don't require any other connectivity for the given IPv6 addresses I'd use [ULA space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_local_address): pick a somewhat random /64 from within `fd00::/8` and use that between the servers.

Comment: @Aragon0 Don't just use `fd00::/8` or you'll defeat the whole purpose. [Use a generator](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/272/645) to pick a random range within that block.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thank you for pointing that out! Luckily I haven't had the time to set it up yet, so I will use the generator.